# Anaglyph (3D) digital artwork with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d-multimedia

Is it possible to take digital artwork and create an anaglyph (3D) version of it in Photoshop (or any similar program)? How?

I would like show some digital artwork in stereoscopic 3D.

I'm aware that for photographs you need two pictures taken from diferent positions. Since I want to apply this effect to digital artwork, I don't know how to create these two pictures.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an anaglyph you need TWO images/photos depicting a scene from two slightly different angles.

Photoshop tutorial available [here](http://www.opentutorial.com/Make_3d_images).

Comment: I don't have two photos because I'm talking about digital artwork. Will make the question more clear. Thanks.

Comment: To use any standard anaglyph techiques you'll still need to start with two images. Start with your existing image as the left eye and create a copy for the right eye. On the right eye image, move things (pixels, shapes) horizontally (via Photoshop layers, cut/paste, 'push' tool, etc.) to simulate depth. The greater the *horizontal* movement, the more "depth" you'll see in the resulting anaglyph. It will take a lot of practise and you'll probably do best to simulate layers at different depths rather than true 3D. With only one starting image, though, an anaglyph will always be a compromise.